# Check if an Uri from the FileProvider exist and is valid

Tags: android, file, android-studio, uri

I have a Uri with this format:

```
String myuri= "content://mypic/2017_01_mypic.jpg"
```

I would like to check if the file exist on my android app repository. I tried this:

```
File file = new File(URI.create(myuri))
if(file.exists()){//code here}
```

but it does not work. How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Use `ContentResolver ` .

Comment: What do you mean with app repository? And how dit you obtain that content scheme?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ContentResolver` In the same way the one used the get path form a URI .

```
 String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
    // Change the projection ap per need 
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(content_uri), projection, null, null, null);
    if (cur != null) {
        // File exist
    } else {
        // Invalid URI
    }
```

Comment: No. No good code. There does not have to be such a file on file system. You started ok. But if cursor not null then you are ready.